# How to replace multibyte characters in ruby using gsub?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I have a problem with saving records in MongoDB using Mongoid when they contain multibyte characters. This is the string:

```
a="Chris \xA5\xEB\xAE\xDFe\xA5"
```

I first convert it to BINARY and I then `gsub` it like this:

```
a.force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(0xA5.chr,"oo")
```

...which works fine:

```
=> "Chris oo\xEB\xAE\xDFeoo"
```

But it seems that I can not use the `chr` method if I use `Regexp`:

```
a.force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(/0x....?/.chr,"")
NoMethodError: undefined method `chr' for /0x....?/:Regexp
```

Anybody with the same issue?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: so you want to replace all the non ascii characters with 'oo' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with interpolation

```
a.force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(/#{0xA5.chr}/,"")
```

gives

```
"Chris \xEB\xAE\xDFe"
```

EDIT: based on the comments, here a version that translates the binary encode string to an ascii representation and do a regex on that string

```
a.unpack('A*').to_s.gsub(/\\x[A-F0-9]{2}/,"")[2..-3] #=>"Chris "
```

the [2..-3] at the end is to get rid of the beginning [" and and trailing "]

NOTE: to just get rid of the special characters you also could just use

```
a.gsub(/\W/,"") #=> "Chris"
```

Comment: Which makes more sense, to apply chr to a stringy thing, not a regex.

Comment: Yes indeed, it makes just sense! However, how can I use regex so as to avoid specifying each string distinctively?

Comment: what is the pattern you want to use ? you just have to treat the encoded chars as regular ones eg gsub(/#{0xA5.chr}{2}/,"") replaces 0xA5 only if it occurs 2 times

Comment: I want to replace the multibytes in one go, using something like ```/0x....?/```. I think this pattern describes all of the ```\xA5 \xEB \xAE \xDFe \xA5```

Comment: p a.force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(/#{0xA5.chr}...../,"") gives "Chris " but if you want to use the binary presentation as a string where you use your pattern upon you have to start with a string representation like b="Chris \\xA5\\xEB\\xAE\\xDF\\xA6" 
p b.gsub(/(\\x[0-9A-F]{2})+/,"") #=>"Chris "

Comment: That has worked, thank you! However, I am not able to edit the strings beforehand which means that I am looking for a way to parse them in their original form (this is with a single"```\```")

Comment: since you insist 8>) i added that to my answer

Answer (score 4):

The actual string does not contain the literal characters \xA5: that is just how characters that would otherwise be unprintable are shown to you (similar when a string contains a newline ruby shows you \n).

If you want to change any non ascii stuff you could do this

```
a="Chris \xA5\xEB\xAE\xDFe\xA5"
a.force_encoding('BINARY').encode('ASCII', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => 'oo')
```

This starts by forcing the string to the binary encoding (you always want to start with a string where the bytes are valid for its encoding. binary is always valid since it can contain arbitrary bytes). Then it converts it to ASCII. Normally this would raise an error since there are characters that it doesn't know what to do with but the extra options we've passed tell it to replace invalid/undefined sequences with the characters 'oo'

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks!